# How to click page numbers?

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to click page numbers one by one but getting error.

```
<span class="p-paginator-pages">
    <button class="p-paginator-page p-paginator-element p-link p-highlight">1</button>
    <button class="p-paginator-page p-paginator-element p-link">2</button>
          :
    <button class="p-paginator-page p-paginator-element p-link">5</button>

def click_page_number(self, page_num):
    page_number = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selctor('span[class="p-paginator-pages"] button') 
    ele_num = page_number.get_attribute("innerHTML")
    if page_num == ele_num.text:
        print(ele_num.text)
        ele_num.click()
```

The following error shows:
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: you have to click button, not innerHTML or text inside button - `page_number.click()`

Comment: to get many items use `find_elements_...` with char **s** in word `elements`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to click `button` not `innerHTML` or `text`

To get many items you can use `find_elements_...` with char **s** in word `elements`

```
def click_page_number(self, page_num):

    all_buttons = self.driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('span[class="p-paginator-pages"] button')

    for button in all_buttons:
        if button.text == page_num:
            button.click()
            break # don't check other buttons
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and the code works. For that method, I have to specify page numbers. is there a loop method to click the page numbers without specify each number?

Comment: if there is button with text `"Next"` or `">"` then you can click it on every page to visit all pages without using numbers.

Comment: Somehow I forgot about the "Next" button. I'll loop with the next button. Thank you!